# How to initialize a class type used as a function parameter

Tags: c++, ubuntu, visual-c++, hdl, verilator

I am trying to get a handle on HDL to C++ conversions and have hit a bit of a snag.
The conversion using Verilator on Ubuntu is easy enough but one data type is annoying me.

The top code in the hierarchy is...

```
#include <iostream>
#include "VDorQ24Syms.h"
#include "VDorQ24.h"

using namespace std;
// FUNCTIONS
VDorQ24Syms::VDorQ24Syms(VDorQ24* topp, const char* namep)
    // Setup locals
    : vm_namep(namep)
    , vm_activity(false)
    , vm_didInit(false)
    // Setup submodule names
{
    // Pointer to top level
    tOPp = topp;
    // Setup each module's pointers to their submodules
    // Setup each module's pointer back to symbol table (for public functions)
    tOPp->Vconfigure(this, true);
    // Setup scope names
}
```

Passing data to the function

```
VDorQ24Syms::VDorQ24Syms(VDorQ24* topp, const char* namep)
```

is what I'm not getting. The second parameter is easy to understand. The first, not so much.

By this I mean, what is the compiler expecting me to pass? Which data type?

I want to pass data like so...

```
VDorQ24* randomCharacter;
if (VDorQ24Syms(randomCharacter, szAscii) == /*condition*/)
{
    return /*value*/;
}
```

But 'randomCharacter' is uninitialized.

```
VDorQ24* randomCharacter = /*How do I initialize this?*/;
```

Comment: A pointer to `VDorQ24`. Why not look in the `"VDorQ24.h"` header file for a possible class definition?

Comment: I've redefined the problem as how to initialize the variable to pass. Any ideas?

Comment: @loumbut5 Your Program is ill formed. Any name that starts with a double underscore or starts with an underscore and a capital letter is reserved for standard implementation. That apply to any scope.

Comment: Please, post a minimal, but **complete** example of code. It will help us a lot, and we might be able to help you more efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You example is not complete, but this might help you.

Your variable `randomCharacter` is not an instance of your class `VdorQ24`, it's a pointer to your class.

If you want to initialize your variable, set it to `nullptr`:

```
VdorQ24* randomCharacter = nullptr; // now you can be 100% certain that it's null.
```

If you acually wanted to create a new instance of `VdorQ24`, you can simply forget about the pointer and use values. Here we call the default constructor:

```
// Not a pointer, initialize the instance of your class directly.
VDorQ24 randomCharacter;

//              v---- Here we send a pointer to your variable using the '&' operator.
if (VDorQ24Syms(&randomCharacter, szAscii) == /*condition*/)
{
    return /*value*/;
}
```

If you want to send parameter to the constructor, you can use this syntax:

```
VDorQ24 randomCharacter{param1, param2};
```

In fact, any type can be initialized with this syntax, even int and arrays:

```
int a{1};

float b[] = {1.f, 2.f, 3.f};
```